# Swift View is not hiding subViews correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

**UPDATE AT THE BOTTOM**

Inside my `ViewController` I have a `TableView` with `CustomCells`. The content being presented in those `cells` is depending on the `userInput`. I think the best way to explain the problem is to actually show it:

**1. adding `cells` to the `tableView`:**

[looking as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pewd.png)

**2. Problem: after dismissing the `ViewController` and going back to it:**

[showing views that should actually be hidden in the first `cell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdMfu.png)

By the way, when I open the View-Hirarchy in the Debugger, it is being displayed correctly !

Here is also another `video` for a better understanding: [video](https://gofile.io/d/AvXeZH)
In this case I didn't add an `image`, but when going back to the `viewController` it still shows the `imageContainerView`(shadow) and also the `content` for the first cell.

**Code:**

My code is quite complex and messy so I you can follow me here:

**setupViews in `CustomCell`:**

I don't think that this is quite helpful, but I also don't think that the `setup` is the issue here.

```
func setupViews(){
    
    contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
    contentView.addSubview(mainStackView)
    
    // main StackView
    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    
    mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mainStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    mainStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    mainStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    //constrain wish label
    labelHeightConatraint = label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    labelHeightConatraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    labelHeightConatraint.isActive = true
    
    // constrain checkButton
    checkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    checkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    checkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    checkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(secondaryStackView)
    secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint = secondaryStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
    secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    
    secondaryStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageContainerView)
    imageContainerWidthConstraint = imageContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
    imageContainerWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    imageContainerWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    imageContainerView.addSubview(shadowLayer)
    shadowLayer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    shadowLayer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    shadowLayer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    shadowLayer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageContainerView.addSubview(wishImage)
    wishImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    wishImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    wishImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    wishImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    
    secondaryStackView.addArrangedSubview(thirdHelperView)
    thirdHelperView.addSubview(thirdStackView)
    thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint = thirdHelperView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
    thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    
    thirdStackView.addArrangedSubview(priceView)
    priceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    priceView.addSubview(priceImage)
    priceView.addSubview(priceLabel)
    
    thirdStackView.addArrangedSubview(linkView)
    linkView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    linkView.addSubview(linkImage)
    linkView.addSubview(linkTextView)
    
    thirdStackView.addArrangedSubview(noteView)
    noteView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    noteView.addSubview(noteImage)
    noteView.addSubview(noteLabel)

    priceImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    priceImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    priceImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    priceImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    
    priceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    priceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    
    linkImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    linkImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    linkImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    linkImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

    linkTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    linkTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    linkTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    
    noteImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noteView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    noteImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdStackView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    noteImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    noteImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

    noteLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noteView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    noteLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noteImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    noteLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: noteView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

**more importantly: `cellForRowAt`**, where I actually hide/show the different views depending on the content. As you can see I actually call `.isHidden` on the `ImageContainerView, priceView, linkView & noteView` , if there content is empty ( which it is in the first cell )

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! WhishCell
    
    cell.label.text = ""
    cell.linkTextView.text = ""
    cell.priceLabel.text = ""
    cell.noteLabel.text = ""
    cell.wishImage.image = UIImage()
    
    let currentWish = self.wishData[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.label.text = currentWish.name
    cell.linkTextView.hyperLink(originalText: "Link öffnen", hyperLink: "Link öffnen", urlString: currentWish.link)
    cell.priceLabel.text = currentWish.price
    cell.noteLabel.text = currentWish.note
    cell.wishImage.image = currentWish.image
    
    cell.setupSuccessAnimation()
    
    cell.noteView.isHidden = false
    cell.priceView.isHidden = false
    cell.linkView.isHidden = false
    cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = false
    cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    
    if currentWish.image == nil || !currentWish.image!.hasContent {
        cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = true
        print("but its truue:  \(cell.imageContainerView.isHidden)")
        if currentWish.price != "" {
            cell.thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
            cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
        }
        if currentWish.link != "" {
            cell.thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
            cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
        }
        if currentWish.note != "" {
            cell.thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
            cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += 30
        }
    } else {
        cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 90
        cell.thirdHelperViewHeightConstraint.constant = 90
    }
    
    if currentWish.price == "" {
        cell.priceView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    if currentWish.link == "" {
        cell.linkView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    if currentWish.note == "" {
        cell.noteView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

I have no idea why this happens. I don't think something is wrong with the setup as it works if I actually add the `cells`. It is simply not hiding the views when it actually should. The `cellheight` is also working as expected. Just the damn hiding...

I know this is a lot but I hope my problem is clear. If you need any thing more just let me know!

**Update:**
I added two `print-statements` inside `cellForRowAt` and is actually printing this:

```
    print("but its truue:  \(cell.imageContainerView.isHidden)")
    print("but its truue:  \(cell.shadowLayer.isHidden)")
```

> but its truue:  true
>
> but its truue:  false

so it is hiding the `imageConatinerView` correctly but not `shadowLayer` even though `shadowLayer` is a `subView` of `imageContainerView`??! Im stuck here...

Comment: Which method calls setupViews on cell? By the way, a xib would really simplify that.

Comment: @Sulthan never worked with xib, prefer it like this tbh. setupViews is called in the `cells` `init`

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIView debugging method to debug your UI.
There are four useful methods to debug:

- hasAmbiguousLayout:
- exerciseAmbiguityInLayout：
- exerciseAmbiguityInLayout：
- _autolayoutTrace:

And then you can use Xcode UI Debug to review your UI

Comment: I looked at the View Hirarchy and it looks perfectly fine there but not on the actual device. Any idea ?